# Fix the version conflict - google-services

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm a rookie at android platform and I'm trying to do a Login system with firebase in it. 
I've watched and followed a few tutorials and the code is all good. My problem is on "Module:app", where I have a conflict with versions:

*Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.2.2.*

Here is my gradle code: 
**Module:app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.diogo.VicenteAPP"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.2'
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If I erase this line:    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services', it will not appear any errors but the application blows up

What should I do to solve this headache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all of them (`gms-services-version`) same version :-

Use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.2.2'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
```